# Build a balanced panel keeping observations that are repeated every year

Tags: r, panel

I would like to keep only the complete observations for all the years, how can I proceed?

I have the following example:

```
structure(list(variable = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5), Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

I would like to get:

```
structure(list(variable = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5), Year = c(2010, 
2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

The example is simple, but I need to do this for a vast dataset with the idea of building a balanced dashboard. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `subset` with `table`

```
yr <- unique(df$Year)
subset(df, variable %in% names(which(table(variable[Year %in% yr]) == 
       length(yr))))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, grouped by 'variable', `filter` those variables having number of distinct 'Year' (`n_distinct`) same as those in the entire data

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(variable) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(Year) == n_distinct(.$Year)) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  variable  Year
     <dbl> <dbl>
1        1  2010
2        1  2011
3        1  2012
4        3  2010
5        3  2011
6        3  2012
7        5  2010
8        5  2011
9        5  2012
```